# Tizen .Net App does not launch on Tizen 4 Wearables - VS2019 - Mac - Mono 6.4

Tags: .net, visual-studio, mono, tizen

If I set version 4 on manifest, the app installs, but it doesn't launch on Tizen 4 Wearables... If I set version 5/5.5 it only works on 5/5.5 emulators...
Someone already solved this or can help me with this issue? 
**It is possible to develop Tizen 4 Wearable Apps on VS2019?**

```
12-24 11:51:43.541 : Warning / AUL ( 3118 : 3118 ) : launch.c: app_request_to_launchpad_for_uid(301) > request cmd(0) : appid(com.APP), target_uid(5001)
12-24 11:51:43.553 : Info / AMD_TIME_TRACKER ( 2439 : 2439 ) : amd_time_tracker.c: __on_launch_starting(115) > Starting application: com.APP
12-24 11:51:43.553 : Warning / AMD_SHARE ( 2439 : 2439 ) : amd_share.c: __on_launch_prepare_end(603) > No sharable path: 3118 com.APP
12-24 11:51:43.557 : Warning / AMD ( 2439 : 2439 ) : amd_signal.c: _signal_send_proc_prelaunch(151) > send a prelaunch signal done: appid(com.APP) pkgid(com.APP) attribute(608) category(10)
12-24 11:51:43.577 : Error / RESOURCED ( 2619 : 2619 ) : block.c: block_prelaunch_state(157) > insert data com.APP, table num : 4
12-24 11:51:43.597 : Info / RESOURCED ( 2619 : 2619 ) : proc-main.c: proc_add_program_list(543) > com.gAPP is added in the program info
12-24 11:51:48.085 : Info / APP_SHORTCUT_WIDGET ( 3351 : 3351 ) : AppWidgetApp.cpp: operator()(399) > [0;32mcom.APP need to update [0;m
12-24 11:51:48.089 : Debug / APP_SHORTCUT_WIDGET ( 3351 : 3351 ) : AppWidgetInstanceView.cpp: onUpdate(160) > app launched com.APP
12-24 11:51:48.089 : Debug / APP_SHORTCUT_WIDGET ( 3351 : 3351 ) : AppWidgetViewController.cpp: _setWidgetContentInfo(1483) > 0x20de2a8, com.samsung.tizen.bixby-voice|1173|0 com.APP|1177|0 com.samsung.w-logs2|1170|0 com.samsung.clocksetting|1175|0 com.samsung.w-music-player|1166|0 com.samsung.shealth|1168|0
```

Comment: is this a hello-world app?

Comment: No, it is a "normal" app. It runs when I use VS2017 with Mono 5, but when I try to upgrade VS/Mono it doesn't launch on devices or emulators w/ Tizen 4.

Comment: so it's a regression, which is very important to mention, please edit your question

Comment: Sorry, only yesterday i noticed that. I installed 5.5 stuff and launched it in a 5.5 emulator. But it is not what I want, I want it working on Tizen 4 Wearables. Anyway, i'll be more specific on the question. Thanks

Comment: @WagnerSilva have you solved it? Having the same problem.

Comment: @RomanSamoilenko We couldn't install because Catalina was unsupported. But, I have some good news: they updated the Tizen VS Extension, and now Catalina is supported: https://docs.tizen.org/application/vstools-mac/overview/ :)

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't install because Catalina was unsupported. But they updated the Tizen VS Extension, and now Catalina is supported: docs.tizen.org/application/vstools-mac/overview